# Remove certificate from Ubuntu

Tags: server, ssl

I have followed below steps to install a trusted authority certificate:

```bsh
sudo cp mycert.cer /usr/share/ca-certificates/mycert.pem
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Now, I want to remove this certificate as it is going to expire soon. Can someone please provide me steps to uninstall a previously installed certificate?

Comment: The first command copied a file to`/usr/share/ca-certificates/mycert.pem`. Try removing the file and run the second and third command again.

Comment: @danzel Thanks for your response. I have removed mycert.pem now only thing that I see in /usr/share/ca-certificates/ path is Mozilla director. I have tried to run sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates & sudo update-ca-certificates commands and I have removed mycert certificate from 'certificate to activate list' and it does show that it has removed those cets. but When I go and browse my service remotely I still find this old certificate being used. Can you suggest other steps to help me here. Do I need to reboot ubuntu server to after following 2nd and 3rd command

Comment: @Rinzwind, I tried this step but still I see that old certificate is being used when I browse services remotely. do know other method to help me remove this old certificate. Do I need to reboot server to make it work